# VSCode auto format on paste removes leading new lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I paste copied text in vscode, it removes all leading newlines.

Copied Text:

[image: Copied Text]

Cursor Position:

[image: Cursor Position]

Pasted Result:

[image: Pasted Result]

I can't seem to tell VSCode to preserve the leading newlines. I know I can add a new line before I paste, but that is dumb and I shouldn't have to do that. I still want auto format on to fix my indentation and such.

Everything I search for brings up questions on trailing spaces and other stuff like that. No one else else seems to have issue.

Answer (score 0):

This 'feature' you've mentioned is part of "Format On Paste" option.

The whole feature can be turned off in File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Formatting -> Format On Paste

[image: Screen of accessing the setting]

As far as I know sadly there is no option of disabling only newline removal from "Format On Paste" feature.